# Code Returns Error?(Python) itemconfigure is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am making a timer. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
import time
Screen=Tk()
Screen.resizable(0,0)
myText=Label(Screen,text="Welcome To X Timer!",font=(None,50),bg="green")
myText.pack()
aText=Label(Screen,text="0:0",font=(None,30))
aText.pack()
def start_timer():
    x=1
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
        x=x+1
        itemconfigure(aText,text=x)
strBTN=Button(Screen,text="Start",bg="purple",font= 
("Helvetica",45),command=start_timer)
strBTN.pack()
Screen.mainloop()
```

But on line 14 is says: Error:itemconfigure is not defined. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what it is you're trying to do, but your `start_timer` function is an infinite busy loop that will hang your GUI, so I assume that's *not* it! Maybe you meant to call `Tk.after`?

```
def start_timer(x=0):
    x+=1
    Screen.after(1000, lambda x=x: start_timer(x))
    # 1000 is the time (in milliseconds) before the callback should be invoked again
    # lambda x=x... is the callback itself. It binds start_timer's x to the scope of
    # the lambda, then calls start_timer with that x.
    itemconfigure(aText,text=x)
```

I'm going out on a limb and say that you expect `itemconfigure(aText, text=x)` to change the text on the label? You should instead be using:

```
    ...
    aText.config(text=x)
```

Comment: Note that even after you do this, you may not get the behavior you expect. Try pressing "start" more than once.

Comment: why did you delete my while loop,and why did you delete that the value of x increases every second? Those are important for timers

Comment: @KitKatFam because your loop doesn't work. That was explained in the first sentence.

Comment: @KitKatFam the `while True` loop is what was locking up your code. I re-implemented it in a way that actually works (note that x is still incremented every call)

Comment: @KitKatFam note also that I explained that in my answer: "your `start_timer` function is an infinite busy loop that will hang your GUI"

Comment: ohh..But can you explain " Screen.after(1000, lambda x=x: start_timer(x))" more in debt,even after reading,that is the thing i still dont understand.Can you like break it into parts

Comment: @KitKatFam I need more context to know what you need there. I devoted three lines of comments to explaining it, and am not sure how best to address your confusion.

Comment: "x=x:" explain that part as if you would to a little kid,not a experienced programmer.Thats the only part i dont get. I am a kid btw

Comment: @KitKatFam the keyword `lambda` starts a lambda expression, which is an anonymous function. `lambda x: x + 1` is the same as `def pretend_i_have_no_name(x): return x+1`, except it has no name. the `x=x` in this code block is probably unnecessary, but it binds the `x` in the outer scope (the one keeping track of the time) to the `x` in the inner scope (the one we're using to call `start_timer` next time around). This might be more clear if it was written as `lambda start=x: start_timer(start)`.

Comment: @KitKatFam though as I mentioned, it's probably unnecessary here. `lambda: start_timer(x)` *should* work identically.

Comment: @KitKatFam I didn't, but whoever did probably did so because they felt that "This question doesn't show any research effort, is unclear, or not useful" (the hover text of the downvote error)

Answer (score 0):

To change the text of a Label you have to use Label's method `config()`. So, instead of `itemconfigure(aText,text=x)`, do `aText.config(text=x)`. I think `itemconfigure()` function doesn't exist.

Also, there are other problems. For example, if you define a function with an infinite loop as a button callback, the button will always remain pressed (buttons remain pressed till the callback finishes). That's why I recommend you to use Screen's method `after()` at the end of the callback, and make it execute the same function.
`after()` executes a function after the number of milliseconds entered, so `Screen.after(1000, function)` will pause the execution during a second and execute the function.
Also you can use `s` variable to store the seconds. When `s` equals 60, it resets to 0 and increases in 1 the number of minutes (`m`).
Here you have the code:

```
from tkinter import*

Screen=Tk()
Screen.resizable(0,0)

myText=Label(Screen,text="Welcome To X Timer!",font=(None,50),bg="green")
myText.pack()

aText=Label(Screen,text="0:0",font=(None,30))
aText.pack()

def start_timer():
    global s, m, aText, Screen
    aText.config(text = str(m) + ":" + str(s))
    s += 1
    if s == 60:
        s = 0
        m += 1
  Screen.after(1000,start_timer)

s = 0
m = 0

strBTN=Button(Screen,text="Start",bg="purple",font=("Helvetica",45),command=start_timer)
strBTN.pack()

Screen.mainloop()
```

This one should work (in my computer it works properly). If you don't understand something just ask it.

Comment: dosent work,when i run it and you click the button,it freezes and report problem to microsoft..

Comment: @KitKatFam That's a different problem, that's because you have an infinite loop in your code